# Ubuntu 18.04 uploads heavy traffic when connect to openvpn!

Tags: networking, openvpn

When I connect to my openvpn server ubuntu starts upload heavy traffic. I see traffic for upload getting high in system monitor.
I also use nethogs to see whats going on but nothing show in nethogs. I also has traffic meter on my mobile phone. I made my phone hotspot and connect ubuntu to it. My mobile traffic meter still shows heavy upload about 2.3MBps and eats my mobile internet traffic.
Anybody has any solutions out there?

Comment: your entire network is being piped over the VPN, but it's also possible that something on the VPN network is dumping data to all connected clients, have you ruled out *incoming* traffic over the VPN tunnel as the data hog?

Comment: @ThomasWard No Ididn't.